# Removing attributes from oracle json object

Tags: json, oracle

Use case:
Application requires a subset of attributes, based on business rules

Example:
Some students do not require to enter in home address

Database : Oracle

Proposed implementation:
Build json object containing all possible attribute named pairs, then selectively remove specific named pairs

Issue:
Hoped to use native oracle function to remove the specified named pair.
e.g json_object.remove_attribute('home_address');
However Oracle do not appear to provide any such method.

Workaround : Convert json_object to VARCHAR2 string, and then use combination of INSTR and REPLACE to remove named pair.

Illustrative code:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_student_json (p_s_ref IN VARCHAR2) IS
  SELECT  JSON_OBJECT(
       ,'s_surname'                     value s.s_surname
       ,'s_forename_1'                  value s.s_forename_1
       ,'s_home_address_1'              value s.s_home_address_1  
  RETURNING VARCHAR2 ) student_json
    FROM   students  s
   WHERE  s.s_ref = p_s_ref;

BEGIN
  FOR x IN cur_student_json (p_s_ref) LOOP
    vs_student_json:=x.student_json;  
    EXIT;
  END LOOP;  

  -- Determine student type
  vs_student_type:=get_student_type(p_s_ref);

  -- Collect list of elements not required, based on student type  
  FOR x IN cur_json_inorout(vs_student_type) LOOP   
     -- Remove element from the json
     vs_student_json:=json_remove(vs_student_json,x.attribute);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Question:
There must be an elegant method to achieve requirement

Answer (score 0):

Classify under RTFM. Needs Oracle 12.2

```
DECLARE

  -- Declare an object of type JSON_OBJECT_T
  l_obj JSON_OBJECT_T;

  -- Declare cursor to build json object
  CURSOR cur_student_json (p_s_ref IN VARCHAR2) IS
  SELECT  JSON_OBJECT(
      ,'s_surname'                     value s.s_surname
      ,'s_forename_1'                  value s.s_forename_1
      ,'s_home_address_1'              value s.s_home_address_1 
    ) student_json
    FROM   students  s
   WHERE  s.s_ref = p_s_ref;

BEGIN

  -- Initialise object
  l_obj := JSON_OBJECT_T();

  -- Populate the object
  FOR x IN cur_student_json (p_s_ref) LOOP
    l_obj:=JSON_OBJECT_T.parse(x.student_json); 
    EXIT;
  END LOOP;  

  -- Determine student type
  vs_student_type:=get_student_type(p_s_ref);

  -- Collect list of elements not required, based on student type  
  FOR x IN cur_json_inorout(vs_student_type) LOOP   
    -- Remove element from the json
    l_obj.remove(x.attribute);
  END LOOP;

  -- Display modified object
  dbms_output.put_line(l_obj.stringify);
END;
/
```